# How to publish existing CRA application to npm(any) repository?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-publish

I have a working application consisting multiple components created using create-react-app, each component is a separate app in itself again created using create-react-app.

All the components are ejected so that I could integrate it together.

Now, I want to publish the components to NPM/Private repository but as per CRA deployment guide, it doesn’t support publishing of CRA based components directly out of the box, it suggests using nwb, but I couldn’t figure out how to use nwb to publish ‘existing’ components.

I have also looked at the one of the medium post where it suggests using the babel-cli to generate the dist/build files  but that’s failing for some babel configuration which works well otherwise.(sorry, don’t have link at the moment as I am posting this from cellphone).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `babel-cli` npm package which will compile your react application code and then you can publish it using `npm publish` command, the detailed steps are as follows.

- Install the babel-cli package in your create-react-app using `npm install babel-cli` command.
- Create `.babelrc` file and add following contents to use "react-app" preset provided by babel.

```
{
        "presets": [["react-app"]],
}
```

- Add `distribute` command in `package.json` using following code, this command compiles the code from `src` folder to `dist` folder. Generally, I do not include my test files in published library so the `--ignore` argument skips the tests files like `*spec.js and *test.js`, this argument is optional and you can remove `--ignore spec.js,test.js` if you would like to include test files in your published library. The `--source-maps` argument includes the source maps for the included source files :

```
    "distribute": "set NODE_ENV=production&&babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore spec.js,test.js --source-maps"
```

- Execute the command `npm run distribute` which will generate the files in `dist` folder.
- Set `private: false` in package.json to make available for publish
- Set main file of your distributed package using following command, in my case I directly use `App.js`

```
"main": "dist/App.js"
```

- Add following code for publishing the package and provide repository related details

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": ""    
  }
```

- You can use `npm run publish` command to distribute your react app source code as library.